# Проблема с MapReduce

Tags: map-reduce, java, hadoop

Пишу программу, используя Hadoop MapReduce.     
Что-то совсем запутался с тем, как написать методы map и reduce, так, чтобы они работать со следующей задачей:

Входной файл имеет следующий вид:   
1 2          
1 3  
1 4  
2 3  
4 3  
...   
Здесь просто список вершин. Напремер "1 2" - т.е. есть направленное ребро из вершины 1 в вершину 2 (разделены табуляцией).

Нужно найти вершины с наибольшим числом "входящих" ребер и найти среднюю степень вершины в графе (для каждой вершины средняя степень = количество "входящий" ребер / общее число ребер) Не пойму как написать mapper и reducer...

Вообще хочу иметь дело с таким объектом: `(vertice_number, incomming_edge_number)`    
- `vertice_number` - номер вершины   
- `incomming_edge_number` - число входящих ребер

Answer (score 1):

Не знаю, как выразить это в терминах Hadoop, но вообще все примерно так:

1. Общее число ребер равно количеству записей в исходном файле. Пусть это будет N.
2. Считаем кол-во входящих ребер:

2.1 map для исходных данных даст следующий результат (первое значение - вершина, второе - кол-во входящих ребер):

```
2 1

3 1

4 1

3 1

3 1
```

2.2 reduce для результата map даст (просто сумма с группировкой по номеру вершины):

```
2 1

3 3

4 1
```

Осталось посчитать степень для каждой вершины. Это еще одна функция map:

```
2 1/N

3 3/N

4 1/N
```

Осталось выразить это в терминах Hadoop.

Comment: > Осталось выразить это в терминах Hadoop.
Собственно, это единственная проблема...

Comment: @Stas0n Вам дан алгоритм. Остальное вы можете найти в документации.